# Missing kernel on debian-testing-amd64-DVD-1

Tags: debian, iso-image, linux-kernel

I want to install the Debian testing linux version.
But at a certain point of the installation, an error occurs:

> Impossible to install kernel. a compatible kernel version is missing.

… or something like that...

I see that the image ISO of the DVD is less than 4GB, but is impossible that there is no compatible kernel version for the system.

I have an Asus X53Sc with Intel core I7-2630QM,  Geforce GT 520MX.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct bitness for your system?

Comment: I found the solution.

I download the daily release version of Debian wheezy testing, and finally I install it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I download the daily release version of Debian wheezy testing, and finally I install it properly.

It seems that developers fix this bug.